# How do I generate an xml file without using any libraries?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

i have a list of unique id's like: ID = [123,455,786,234,788]
I have list of the comments = ['hello world', 'this is true','earth is a sphere','please']
and another lists with dates of when the comments were made.

Comment: Yes it may be strange but its for a test, therefore i was trying to see if anyone had any perspective on it. Thanks for your help tho!

Answer (score 1):

python comes with builtin `xml` support.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET                                                                                                                            

country_data_as_string = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
'''


root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
print(root.tag)
```

This example was taken from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: I think the OP has a data structure (not a string) which he want to convert to XML data structure.

Comment: I can't use any import statements

Comment: That is very odd. Anyway, in that case you would have to write your own parser. That is quite a task. Why can't you import modules?

Comment: yes i do! its just a requirement for a test

Comment: can i just print lines like i would for a text file? @grmmgrmm

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure where you are heading with your question. I think it would be best to clarify your initial question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Below (using dummy data)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

data = [{'name':'jack','car_color':'green'},{'name':'ben','car_color':'pink'}]

root = ET.Element('persons')
for entry in data:
    person = ET.SubElement(root, 'person')
    name = ET.SubElement(person, 'name')
    name.text = entry['name']
    color = ET.SubElement(person, 'car_color')
    color.text = entry['car_color']
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
   <person>
      <name>jack</name>
      <car_color>green</car_color>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>ben</name>
      <car_color>pink</car_color>
   </person>
</persons>
```